# WPF 4 DataGrid in a combobox

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to show the WPF DataGrid within the ComboBox control as a combox item. Following is the XAML. The problem here is that it is not showing-up the scrollbar in the grid. i did tried the ScrollViewer setting to true. I also tried setting up the vertical scrollbar to auto and to visible also but no luck so far. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,41,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
        <DataGrid Name="dgCustomers"></DataGrid>
    </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting [ScrollViewer.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms612683) attached properties.

```
  <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,41,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
            <ScrollViewer  Height="100" >
                <DataGrid Width="100"  Height="200"  Name="dgCustomers"></DataGrid>

            </ScrollViewer>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Yes, I did that already but no luck. I have also just tried the same thing but replaced DataGrid with ListBox - it is doing the same with ListBox as well. That is, no vertical scrollbar.

Comment: put DataGrid inside ScrollViewer, it will make vertical scrollbar visible when needed. I have updated the code for the same

Comment: Thanks, it did work! Thanks a lot. I was trying this for almost 5 hours and you did in just minutes! Great, thank you.